# php validating a amount

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have an amount field which always is going to be positive number without decimal points like 10000, 1200, 10, 40 etc.
I am using the code below to check for a valid amount.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/', $_POST['amount'])) {
    $error[] = 'Invalid amount';
}
```

Is it right. And, do i need to check for empty post amount using  empty function of php separately or does above `preg_match` also checks for empty string amount.

Comment: No, you don't need to check for empty string. Your  current regex forces one digit to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), like:

```
if (!abs(filter_var($_POST['amount'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))) {
    $error[] = 'Invalid amount';
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use intval

Comment: does it also reject amount like 0010

Comment: @KuldeepThakur You're right, `intval()` could be enough.

Comment: ok, thanks. What about a positive floating number like 10.5

Comment: @KuldeepThakur see my updated answer.

Comment: @KuldeepThakur you stated these'll be positive numbers without decimal points.

Comment: yes,  these'll be positive numbers without decimal points.

Comment: i have another field which is positive number and may or may not contain decimal point ? What about this case ?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` can handle that too. Please take a look at the link provided in my answer, you can use different filters according to your use case.

Comment: ok thanks. Also does i have to check for empty post variable

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the string to itself when converted to the absolute int value.  It is more readable and maintainable.

```
if ($_POST['amount'] !== abs(intval($_POST['amount']))) {
    $error[] = 'Invalid amount';
}
```